# Python package not seen in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

System - Linux Mint 21.1. I'm using VSCode to write a script.
I'm trying to import Pandas, Numpy, Ta-Lib and others package example: Import numpy

> Error : Import "numpy" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

I tried to install Numpy with with pip, here is the end result:

```
pip install numpy
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.24.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.3 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.10 are installed in '/home/user/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed numpy-1.24.2
```

Why and how can I fixed this?

Comment: Have you tried switching interpreters? On windows use Ctrl+Shift+P and type Select Interpreter. Try all interpreters to see if it works.

Comment: I just created a venv following the instruction on VSCode tutorial and nothing change except that a .venv file has been added to my "project file".
I also looked at Python Interpreter and selected the new .venv option that is now available.
But when trying to import a package, example Numpy, it is still gray and the "Import "numpy" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)" is still there.

Screenshot here
https://ibb.co/QYJv71N

Comment: Thank you Jason, I did try all interpreter available plus the .venv interpreter I created following the VSCode tutorial as described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create and select the newly created .venv interpreter, you still need to use command `pip install numpy` in the terminal to install python package .